# How do you handle casting problems using OPENROWSET?

Tags: t-sql, etl

I am trying to use a txt file that contains only keys in a sql query.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
MyTable
JOIN
OPENROWSET (
         BULK '<File-Of-Ids>.txt',
         FORMATFILE = '<Format-File>.txt'
) B ON MyTable.Id  = B.Id
WHERE 
<a field> = <a value> AND <another field> = <another value>
```

But I'm getting the following error: Error converting datatype nvarchar into bigint.

Seems obvious to me that some casting needs to be done on the input from the file. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what version of sql?

Comment: Looks like 11.00.6523

Answer (score 0):

One of your ID columns has something other than an 0-9 in it. This probably isn't by design. But you can just cast them both to `VARCHAR` to get around this. You probably want to inspect the data though and cleanse it.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, MyTable.Id) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, B.Id)
```

You could also bring your `.txt` file into a `TEMP TABLE` which is declared and formatted. That way, if your source file doesn't match the temp, an error is thrown.

Comment: I got the contents of the file, but there seems to be an encoding problem or something. The first like in my file is "23595408" but when I select from the openrowset, the first entry is "4048793468203774770". I'm going to try and chase this down, but let me know if you see a solution!

Comment: 11.0
1
1 SQLBIGINT 0 100 "\r\0\n\0" 3 Id ""